# all category search ecommerce suggest popular search

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

I made a ecommerce app for learning purpose.
I have implement search box using elasticsearch, it can search and give suggestion item's name.
example :
input -> macbo
suggestion :
laptop macbook 14
laptop mackbok xxxxxx

now I want implement search box for "general" means nothing category selected so when we type a something it's not give us spesific item's name but something like most popular search query/terms.
I cannot figured out how the basic ideas behind this, can someone give me some advise.
Thanks

Comment: please go through my answer and let me know if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for suggestions, not the actual search results and If I understand this correctly then you could use the [term suggestor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#term-suggester) available in Elastisearch.

Comment: yeah , i look something like term not actual search. 
i have implement completion suggester for suggest me some product related the keyword prefix and search_as_type field.
Sorry not really clear give explaination, but i look something like :
when i type : "fac"
it give me like categories product or popular search rather than the product name.
actually i need some like architecture scenario (ecommerce), like i must store every search query in different index so when we search "general" it can get from that index. not really to elastic features